# How to obtain same hash from json

Tags: json, go, hash, cryptography

I need to sign a JSON but I noticed that unmarshaling/marshaling can change JSON's order which might make the signature invalid.

Is there anyway to produce the same hash from a JSON string despite its order?

I've had a look at JOSE but couldn't find the function that actually hashes JSON.

Comment: You should be able to preserve the order if you avoid using `map`s.

Comment: so if I marshal and unmarshal and marshal again it will produce the same order? I'll test

Comment: which version of go are you using?

Comment: @mkopriva Output is deterministic even if you use maps: _"The map keys are sorted and used as JSON object keys..."_ So all in all, output should be deterministic if you don't use custom marshaler in which you screw up the order.

Comment: @icza IFAK starting from Go 1.12+(map value and it will be sorted by key automatically)

Comment: @icza however what about the case where they are first unmarshaling something into a map and then marshaling that map back to json later, the output of the marshaling would not be guaranteed to be the same as the input to the unmarshaling, say in a case where the original input's keys aren't sorted. Not sure if that's the case where OP is seeing the inconsistency of the order though.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, that's true. Unmarshaling and marshaling again might be different. What I'm saying is that marshaling only with `encoding/json`, the output will be deterministic / same. At least if the same Go version is used.

Comment: @icza ok, got it. Thanks

Comment: To verify a signed message you do not need to perform the unmarshall. The signature is made on the JSON string encoded in base64url, and the verification is done directly on the base64. Only if the verification is correct the message is decoded and the unmarshall performed. This is how JWS (Json Web Signature) standard works. Once validated, the order of the nodes is not significant

Comment: Yes, and since signature signing / verification *includes* hashing the message, you might as well follow that idea. That has been tested well and it's nicely symmetric with signing. Just replace the signature with the hash value. You might simply look up an existing signing application and skip the signature calculation: just base 64 the hash instead.

Answer (score 5):

JOSE JWS will absolutely do what you want at the cost of having to manage keys for signatures and verification.

But let's assume that you don't really need the whole key management stuff and general crypto functionality in JOSE and you're not SUPER concerned about performance (so a little string mangling in this process is OK).

You could dumbly unmarshal your JSON and re-marshal it, then just hash that:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    json "encoding/json"
)

// NB These docs are strictly-speaking the same.
const DOCA = "{ \"foo\": 1.23e1, \"bar\": { \"baz\": true, \"abc\": 12 } }"
const DOCB = "{ \"bar\": { \"abc\": 12, \"baz\": true }, \"foo\": 12.3 }"

func hash(doc string) string {
    // Dumb af, but it's a cheap way to specific the most generic thing
    // you can :-/
    var v interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(doc), &v) // NB: You should handle errors :-/
    cdoc, _ := json.Marshal(v)
    sum := sha256.Sum256(cdoc)
    return hex.EncodeToString(sum[0:])
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(DOCA)
    fmt.Printf("Hash: %s\n", hash(DOCA))
    fmt.Println(DOCB)
    fmt.Printf("Hash: %s\n", hash(DOCB))
}
```

The output of this program (at least in the golang docker container) is:

```
{ "foo": 1.23e1, "bar": { "baz": true, "abc": 12 } }
Hash: d50756fbb830f8335187a3f427603944c566772365d8d8e6f6760cd2868c8a73
{ "bar": { "abc": 12, "baz": true }, "foo": 12.3 }
Hash: d50756fbb830f8335187a3f427603944c566772365d8d8e6f6760cd2868c8a73
```

The nice thing about this approach is that, for the cost of some performance, you get insulated from whatever dumb junk you did while marshalling your JSON in the first place (so, unlike other suggestions, you don't have to think about what you might be doing with custom Marshallers and whatnot).  This is especially a big deal when you forget that this was an issue at all in version 3.8 of your code a year from now, implement something that messes with the marshal order, and start breaking things.

And, of course, you could always add the hash to the resulting struct and marshal again with the extra item in the map.  Obviously you want to optimize a bit for performance if you're worried about it at all and properly handle errors, but this is a good prototype anyway :-)

Oh, and if you're super-worried about edge cases biting you, you could also use [canonical JSON](https://github.com/gibson042/canonicaljson-go) to marshal, since it's specifically designed for this type of use (though, honestly, I couldn't come up with an example in my testing where c-json worked but go's default json didn't).